# JS pushState without direct links

Tags: javascript, seo

I'm looking for a way to support SEO for content which is loading via AJAX. My site handles urls for example: www.example.com/part/{number}. Then on a homepage JS executes AJAX request and receives a content. Inside the AJAX callback the pushState is used.

Will the Googlebot respect dynamic content (without duplicate) if the homepage has always the same content? If not, are there ways to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the Googlebot respect dynamic content (without duplicate) if the homepage has always the same content?

Probably not (although they do pay *some* attention to JS these days).

> If not, are there ways to do that?

Use pushState properly. When you change the URL with it, have the JS change the DOM to reflect what the server would deliver if the URL was requested.

Don't load the default content, then examine the URL with client side code, then modify it. That defeats the object of `pushState` and you might as well go back to [the bad old days of hashbangs](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs).

Comment: The problem is that dynamic content appears on a modal window (like lightbox). So the homepage is always same. What do you think about use the escape_fragment where googlebot will see only content of the modal window?

Comment: Escape fragment is horrible. It is a hack to get around the problems introduced by overuse of Ajax before `pushState` was available. A "modal window" is just a div in the page and some CSS to cover everything else up. Have the server deliver an HTML document with that div and that CSS.

Comment: Thanks. This will be the best option.